# Creating A Slideshow On A Website

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, flash, dhtml

I understand that there are many methods to creating a slideshow on a website, but that isn't my question.

What I really want to know is what is the most mainstream method of creating a slideshow on a website.

What do you recommend?

So far I've seen Jquery, Javascript, CSS & DHTML, and Flash. The first thing that comes to mind for me is flash, then second Javascript.

What are your thoughts?

Comment: I don't mind more opinions so....Yeah!

Comment: I think Javascript(e.g jQuery) is the best choice. Here is a nice example of slideshow in jQuery http://css-tricks.com/examples/AnythingSlider/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally, I would go for jQuery over Flash. It's likely that a jQuery implementation will be far more lightweight than Flash, and jQuery provides such a rich set of effects it makes it easy to create great-looking slideshows.

Plus, there are literally hundreds of existing jQuery implementations around on the web, so you can just find one that provides all the features you require and drop it in to your site.

Comment: Personally, I don't have any experience with JQuery. If you have the time, do you mind posting an example?

But for right now, I'll just go google-hunting

Comment: Try searching for some existing jQuery slideshow implementations: http://www.dynamicwp.net/articles-and-tutorials/top-20-jquery-slideshow-and-image-gallery-tutorials/

Answer (score 0):

I would go for a basic slideshow in Javascript. Lots of webdevelopers are steering away from Flash for basic stuff like this. One of the reasons is that Flash doesn't run great on mobile devices. For myself I don't use flash because my visitors ain't waiting to be amazed by my super fancy slideshow. Mostly if they use a slideshow they want to see pictures.

That doesn't mean that you can't create super fancy slideshows with Javascript.

Comment: I see, good point. Thanks for your answer Pickels!

How do you know that visitors don't like a little eye candy? ;)

Comment: Because most visitors are coming to your website with a task and they don't want to be annoyed or bothered completing their task.

Comment: Smart answer. I'll think of that when I'm making my websites.